# Can I read a dynamical length variable using fread without pointers?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, pointers, fread

I am using the `cstdio (stdio.h)` to read and write data from binary files. I have to use this library due to legacy code and it must be cross-platform compatible with Windows and Linux. I have a `FILE* basefile_` which I use to read in the variables `configLabelLength` and `configLabel`, where `configLabelLength` tells me how much memory to allocate for `configLabel`.

```
unsigned int configLabelLength; // 4 bytes
char* configLabel = 0;          // Variable length

fread((char *) &configLabelLength, 1, sizeof configLabelLength, baseFile_);
configLabel = new char[configLabelLength];
fread(configLabel,1, configLabelLength,baseFile_);

delete [] configLabel; // Free memory allocated for char array
configLabel = 0; // Be sure the deallocated memory isn't used
```

Is there a way to read in `configLabel` without using a pointer? For example is there a solution where I can use the c++ vector library or something where I do not have to worry about pointer memory management.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using C++'s file streams?

Comment: @Cog: Right at the top of the question. :) And +1 for seeking to use vector.

Comment: @Cogwheel I am forced to use `cstdio (stdio.h)` due to legacy code. I know this is not ideal.

Comment: Where's my caffeine??!?!! /wanderawayslowly

Comment: If he is stuck using an old C library then he can't use C++ iterators like back_inserter and he is stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
unsigned int configLabelLength; // 4 bytes*
fread((char *) &configLabelLength, 1, sizeof configLabelLength, baseFile_);

std::vector<char> configLabel(configLabelLength);
fread(&configLabel[0], 1, configLabel.size(), baseFile_);
```

The elements in a vector are contiguous.

---

<sup>*</sup> I assume you know that `unsigned int` isn't necessary always 4 bytes. If you pay attention to your implementation details that's fine, but it'll be a bit easier if you adopt Boost's `cstdint.hpp` and just use `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Gman...that assumption is correct. Due to legacy code and that other less-skilled/experienced users will be using this code, I am trying my best to keep the code readable. I really like boost and implement it else where, but I am tentative to implement boost for variables. 

Our ICD specifically uses the term `unsigned int`, so I want to try to match the ICD for other users. :p

Comment: Big agreement with your 4 bytes comment. Binary file and network code should always use objects with specified sizes, alignments and byte order. Forex, I use a C++ struct named le_uint32_t to make code work on PowerPC with Intel binary formats.